# using else in inline conditional python

Tags: python, if-statement, inline

I know I can do this:

```
z = a if switch == 1 else z = b
```

but what if I want `z=a if switch=1, z=b if switch=2, and z=c if switch=3`? Is there a python valid way to write this as a single line?

something like:

`z = a if switch == 1 else z = b if switch == 2 else z = c`

Thanks, just learning Python now (obviously).

Comment: FWIW, `z = a if switch == 1 else z = b` is not valid since the assignment `z = b` is a statement, not an expression.  I think you mean `z = a if switch == 1 else b` :-)

Comment: This is a recipe for confusing code, which is not Pythonic. If you're got something more complicated than a single ternary operator can handle, don't use ternary operators.

Comment: Or, in the case of python, a "conditional expression" which is the equivalent to a ternary operator in other languages :-).

Comment: mgilson, thank you, yes indeed - sorry to be so new to this all!
jwilner - I don't disagree, this is more a question of what is possible, not what is recommended. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
z = a if switch == 1 else (b if switch == 2 else c)
```

And you can keep going, but you didn't say what to use after c if it wasn't 3...

Comment: You technically don't need the parens, but personally I think it's a lot more readable with :P

Comment: Oh wow, I actually imagined that this was not doable - it's so cool to see that! Would you just keep nesting parens with more options?

z = a if switch == 1 else (b if switch == 2 else (c if switch == 3 else d))

for example?

Comment: @SindyR  Yes, but at some point, you might want to rethink your strategy, and use a dict lookup or something :)

Comment: I am sure, this is likely not Pythonic at all, but I was curious to see what was possible. :)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen True.  Interestingly, `z = a if b else c if d else e` is accepted by the compiler even though it's ambiguous (you have to know that it is interpreted the way I wrote it instead of `z = (a if b else c) if d else e` -- but `z = a if b if c else d else e` is a syntax error even though it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

if `a`, `b`, `c`, ... are static, then you might as well just use a `dict`:

```
lookup = {1: a, 2: b, 3: c}
z = lookup[switch]
```

It'd probably be most efficient if you could generate `dict` only once and reuse it every time.  Also note that since switch seems to be sequential integers starting at 1, you could also use a `list` (or `tuple`):

```
lookup = (a, b, c)
z = lookup[switch - 1]
```

Comment: thanks, I'll keep this in mind - I am sure that a dict in this case may be more Pythonic, but I like knowing what functions in Python even when idiom doesn't recommend it. ;)